# Nextjs api routes use for upload file

Tags: next.js, multipartform-data

I have followed some tutorials in the internet to upload a file in nextjs 13.
This is the my client side code.

```
 const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', file.url);

  const response = await fetch('/api/file/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  });
```

This is my api routes. pages/api/file/upload.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const data = await req.formData();

    const file = data.get('file') as File;

    if (!file) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'File not found' }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const name = data.get('name') as string;

    if (!name) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'File name not found' }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const fileKey = Date.now() + name;

    /* upload file */

    return NextResponse.json({ data: { fileKey } });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

But this is throwing following error.

```
TypeError: req.formData is not a function
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/file/upload.ts:9:32)
    at /home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:456:16
    at /home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:117:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7057)
    at ContextAPI.with (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:516)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18086)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18847)
    at /home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:106:107
    at NoopContextManager.with (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7057)
    at ContextAPI.with (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:516)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:106:32)
    at apiResolver (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:454:63)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async PagesAPIRouteModule.render (webpack-internal:///(api)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/pages-api/module.js:29:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:314:9)
    at async DevServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:692:31)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/home/dinuka/workspace/co/FE/CollectiveOS_v1.1.0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.64.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:647:17)
API resolved without sending a response for /api/file/upload, this may result in stalled requests.
```

Comment: I have just check with fresh nextjs project. It is working. There route file is in `/src/app/api/upload/route.ts`. May be this code is not working with page api routes.

Comment: I am also stuck here. I am using pages/api/route.ts. Did you find a solution?